# Reflecting on the Reflection Tag

Tags: discussion, tags

I was answering & editing a question involving (one kind of) reflection recently and noticed our [reflection](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reflection) tag currently has no tag guidance and a mix of three very different meanings:

- **Reflection rendering**: visually representing the way that light bounces off surfaces and can produce images of surrounding objects.

  - [Environment mapping without cubemap (need coordinates projection)](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/121974/environment-mapping-without-cubemap-need-coordinates-projection)
  - [Getting the unity pro Water shader to reflect light sources such as spotlights](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/144955/getting-the-unity-pro-water-shader-to-reflect-light-sources-such-as-spotlights)
  - [OpenGL Water reflection seems to follow camera yaw and pitch](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/138306/opengl-water-reflection-seems-to-follow-camera-yaw-and-pitch)
- **Physics/geometric reflection**: calculating the velocity with which one object should bounce off another, or taking a [chiral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chirality_(chemistry)) game entity and producing its mirror image.

  (Technically the real-world physics of this interpretation have a lot in common with the visible light case, but in games we'll generally be applying the math through very different sets of code / tools)

  - [How does one calculate the surface normal, in 2D collisions?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/136073/how-does-one-calculate-the-surface-normal-in-2d-collisions)
  - [Determine the bullet / particle reflection off of a circle in node js using SAT lib functions](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/143052/determine-the-bullet-particle-reflection-off-of-a-circle-in-node-js-using-sat)
  - [Mythbuster: Mirror Operation with Quaternion](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/142460/mythbuster-mirror-operation-with-quaternion)
- **Code reflection**: software that introspects its own structure and types at runtime.

  - [Making generic type T method as a layer of abstraction for Unty3D's EditorGUI field draw methods](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/149923/making-generic-type-t-method-as-a-layer-of-abstraction-for-unty3ds-editorgui-fi)
  - [How can I look up an object given only the name of its type?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/141088/how-can-i-look-up-an-object-given-only-the-name-of-its-type) (I'm the guilty party here)

I think some cleanup here is due. Before making changes I want to solicit input on what the best way to disentangle these might be.

Comment: +1 just for the nice title. Good topic, too though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My current thought:

1. Re-tag the questions about visual effects with `reflection-rendering`

   - Make `reflection` a synonym of `reflection-rendering` since it's the most common use.
2. Un-tag the questions related to physics bounces / transform manipulation. I think these topics are already adequately categorized by the [physics](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physics), [transformation](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transformation), and [geometry](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry) tags.
3. Create a new `reflection-code` tag for the computer science meaning of reflection, with explicit tag guidance to use `reflection-rendering` if asking about how to code reflection shaders and the like. ;)

   (I was tempted to call this "introspection," but I think "reflection" is the first thing most devs type, so I think the tag is more discoverable this way. I don't have any hard evidence though, so please let me know if you agree or would prefer a different alternative)

Comment: Could also call the code-tag `reflection-introspection`. I'll admit that I do not recall ever hearing the word "introspection" before, but with a proper tag wiki and description I'm sure programmers would go "yes, that is the thing I want."  e.g. pulling the first sentence from wikipedia "Reflection is the ability of a computer program to examine, introspect, and modify its own structure and behavior at runtime."

Comment: When typing to search for tags, the tag search engine will present all tags that match what's being typed. So instead of `reflection-code`, the tag should be named `code-reflection` which is closer to proper English (right?). When typing "reflection", users will be prompted with `code-reflection`.

Comment: About `introspection`: if we feel that it is needed, we could simply create a synonym from `code-introspection` to `code-reflection`.

Comment: Alright, I'm going to put this into practice tonight in-between handing out candy for the trick-or-treaters. I think I'll take @AlexandreVaillancourt's suggestion re: `code-reflection` as that sounds better to my ear too If anyone wants to help with the re-tagging, feel free to dive in. :)